# Java Integer null turns into 0

Tags: java

When calling a REST service to save an Integer I've noticed that null value is turned into 0 and I don't know why this is happening. This is my class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "CompanyPreference") public class CompanyPreference {
  public CompanyPreference() {
      super();
  }

  @XmlElement
  private Integer preferenceValueNumber;

  public void setPreferenceValueNumber(Integer preferenceValueNumber) {
      this.preferenceValueNumber = preferenceValueNumber;
  }

  public Integer getPreferenceValueNumber() {
      return preferenceValueNumber;
  }
}
```

and this is my web service

```
@POST
@SecureIt
@Consumes(value = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces(value = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Path("/{companyCode}/{companyType}/preferences/update")
@ApiOperation(value = "Update Company Preferences", response = DefaultResponse.class, authorizations = { @Authorization(value="Bearer") })
public Response savePreferences(@ApiParam(value = "Company Code", required = true) @PathParam("companyCode") String companyCode,
                                @ApiParam(value = "Company Type", required = true) @PathParam("companyType") String companyType,
                                @ApiParam(value = "Array of Company Preference objects", required = true) CompanyPreference[] companyPreferences,
                                @Context ContainerRequestContext crc) throws ResponseError {

  for(int i = 0; i < companyPreferences.length; i++) {
     System.out.println(companyPreferences[i].getPreferenceValueNumber());
  }

}
```

Even though `preferenceValueNumber` is an Integer not a primitive int, it still gets turned into 0 when my request looks like this...

```
[
  { preferenceValueNumber: "" },  //this returns 0
  { preferenceValueNumber: 30 }   //this returns 30 as it should
]
```

How can I keep the original value, null?

Comment: The original value isn't null, it's an empty string

Comment: You could use a plain `int` and use a different value as special flag. Are negative numbers valid values for that parameter? If no just go with `-1`...

Comment: I'd expect an exception to be thrown rather than a null value here... If your API expects an integer and finds a String it shouldn't convert it to `null` nor `0`, it should answer with "400 Bad Request".